# Is there a way to override the default behavior for navigation between cells?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, virtual-machine

I have a fairly large and complex AngularJS application.  At one point i display a dialog box with a column of data fields.  What I am after is a rapid way of entering data.  Here is an example:

[image: Simple picrue if Dialog]

How I want it to work is to be able to enter data, hit the Enter Key and go to the next Result.  When it gets to the end of the column, Go to the next Role (the same as hitting the blue arrow button), and when it gets there, have the first element as focus so the data entry can continue without having to do any extra clicking of the mouse.

Believe it or not all of it is working, however I am getting an error that doesn't seem to be hurting anything.

VM985:5 Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined
    at indexOf ()
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at globalEval (VM501 jquery.min.js:2), :5:40)

The list itself is a simple array of objects that gets refreshed as you go from Role to Role because the number of Items can be different for each Role.  I am using a Focus method that gets triggered whenever you reach the last item in the list:

```
element = document.getElementById("input" + $scope.piece[0].result.id);
          if(element != null) {
            element.focus();
          }
```

I haven't been able to trap for this error, if comes up whenever I try and put focus on the first item on the next Role.  Like I said, it's working fine, just this error is in the log and I hate such errors.

Any ideas?  It is an error from the VM, is there a good way to trap for those?

Some further information.  The error is being caused within the VM.  While to code is sending the document to the next set of values, the default behavior appears to still be happening when leaving the bottom cell for the top cell in the next Role.  The VM is showing this error:

```
> //Placed this eventListener here to avoid potential conflicts with other components.  If sets focus to next editable cell when enter key

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if ((event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 9) && event.target.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
      var form = event.target.form;
      var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(form, event.target);
      if(index+1 >= form.elements.length){
        form.elements[0].focus();
      }else{
        form.elements[index + 1].focus();
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
```

The error is on var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(form, event.target); and the error is "TypeError: Array.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined"

The value the command is trying to reference is the value of the bottom cell of the list which is now gone becuase the lst has been overridden by the new list.  So the dom element the VM is trying to reference no longer exists.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Did you try the "pause on Exception" option from the Chrome debugger?

Comment: Yes, I love the debugger and all the breakpoints tell me everything is fine.  The element is not null, the focus command it working, but that error still appears on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best answer, or even the right answer, but it works and right now that's the main concern.  I was using the same call for moving to the next Role as I was when clicking the blue arrow.  Instead of using that call, I created a new method that does the same thing, only it has a tenth of a second pause before the call that was causing the VM to generate an error.  Since the DOM has been updated by that point, the error doesn't trigger.  it feels more like a work-around than an answer, but I haven't been able to come up with something better just yet.  Any other answers are still requested because i hate this sort of kludge.